# Excel Keep Circle Shapes Centred

Tags: excel, alignment, shapes

I have googled this to death now.

I have 2 circles in Excel centred (Align Center)(Align Middle)
I have my VB code written to refer to Cell A1 in order to get the size. Circle 1 is 30% greater than Circle2. Circle 2 size I get from A2.

Every time I change the values in A1, A2 will change "A1*1.3". My problem is that when the circles change size they are no longer aligned on the centre/ middle.

Is there a way to lock the centers so they dont shift when the shap size changes.

Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Circle1"))
    .Width = Range("A1").Value * 30
    .Height = Range("A1").Value * 30

End With
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Circle2"))
    .Width = Range("A2").Value * 30
    .Height = Range("A2").Value * 30
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: So when they change size is the common point top left? If so then recalc the centres after.

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer aligned on the centre/ middle"? Do you mean there X and Y coordinates on the sheet?